# How can I separate a sum of widgets ordered by a vendor when I am using the select sum in a subquery? I tried group by and it still only gives total

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to separate the sums in a sub query with a group by and I have three tables. I have included my current query below and tables I am using.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    st.stocknumber,
    st.locationnumber,
    P3.vendornumber,
    (
    SELECT SUM
        ( P2.orderquantity )
    FROM
        PH2 P2
        LEFT OUTER JOIN PH1 P1 ON P1.ponumber = P2.ponumber 
    WHERE
        p1.dateordered BETWEEN '10/13/2021' 
        AND '10/13/2022' 
        AND p2.location = 'A1' 
        AND p2.stocknumber = ST.stocknumber 
     Group BY p2.vendornumber
    ) As PHOrderQty
FROM
    stok ST 
    left outer join PH2 P3 on (ST.stocknumber = P3.stocknumber)
WHERE
    ST.location = 'A1' 
    AND ST.stocknumber IN (
        '22-2552'
        'JW00',
        'JS20FT',
        'JW090' 
    ) 
ORDER BY
    stocknumber
```

Data looks like this

Stock Table - ST

| stocknumber | location |
| --- | --- |
| 22-2552 | A1 |

PO Head Table - PH1

| n/a | location | dateordered | ponumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | A1 | 10/14/2022 | 1 |
| NULL | A1 | 10/14/2022 | 2 |
| NULL | A1 | 10/14/2022 | 3 |
| NULL | A1 | 10/14/2022 | 4 |

PO Details Table - PH2

| stocknumber | quantityordered | vendornumber | ponumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22-2552 | 3 | 15 | 1 |
| 22-2552 | 2 | 20 | 2 |
| 22-2552 | 1 | 15 | 3 |
| 22-2552 | 4 | 20 | 4 |

I keep getting back

| stocknumber | location | vendornumber | PHorderQty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22-2552 | A1 | 15 | 10 |
| 22-2552 | A1 | 20 | 10 |

What I should be getting back is

| stocknumber | location | vendornumber | PHorderQty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22-2552 | A1 | 15 | 4 |
| 22-2552 | A1 | 20 | 6 |

Comment: Can you share the DBMS you're currently using?

Comment: I am using SQL Server

Comment: Does the `stok` table have `location`, `locationnumber`, or both? The sample data indicates a string but stores a number, and the query references both (but `A1` can't possibly be equal to `9`).

Comment: Sorry, I meant to put location A1, I have updated the tables.

Answer (score 2):

Try with the following one:

```
SELECT ST.stocknumber,
       PH1.location, 
       PH2.vendornumber,
       SUM(PH2.quantityordered) AS phOrderQty
FROM       stock ST
INNER JOIN head PH1
        ON PH1.location = PH1.location
INNER JOIN details PH2
        ON ST.stocknumber = PH2.stocknumber
       AND PH1.ponumber = PH2.ponumber
WHERE ST.stocknumber IN ('22-2552', 'JW00', 'JS20FT', 'JW090') 
  AND PH1.location = 'A1'
GROUP BY ST.stocknumber,
         PH1.location, 
         PH2.vendornumber
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/YgAFMFBo).

Comment: Sorry I made one mistake with the tables given to me. I will edit the question because the stock number is not in the header of the PO table. That is why I was taking it from the stock table.

Comment: It's sufficient to fix the join conditions. Check the updated answer.